# lock screen when screensaver is deactivated? gdm3

Tags: xorg, 20.04, lightdm, gdm, light-locker

Is it possible to lock screen AFTER screensaver is deactivated in dgm3?

I was using lightdm/light-locker what had this setting

Ubuntu LTS 20.04
GNOME 3.36.2

Comment: Does your screen lock when you press Super/Windows Key + L?